# In hammer.js, how can I make swipe as responsive as possible for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, hammer.js

I'm making a html5 game and testing it out on my iPad.  I'd like to make swiping as responsive as possible, but I'm not sure how to do that.  What I mean is, given some code like this:

```
$('#test_el').hammer().on("swipeup", function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
});
```

How can I make the console log as early as possible when the user swipes up?  One thing I've already done is set the `swipe_velocity` in the [options](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) to a very small number like ".05".  The smaller I make that number, the more responsive swiping becomes.  Perhaps making the number even smaller will get me exactly what I need.  But in its current state, there still seems to be a small delay in the reaction I get when I compare it to a native app with similar controls. I'd like to get rid of that delay but I don't know how.

Comment: Swipe is in general composite event and it has some minimum distance to be triggered before it is recognized as such. Try to adjust "threshold" param to your liking too (default 10 for newest version of the library). Native apps probably base on events closer to "drag"/"dragend" or "touch"/"touchend" which are triggered instantaneously after touching the screen.